# Use a custom font only in test target?

Tags: ios, xcode, uifont

I'd like to use a custom font in iOS in a test target.
ONLY in the test target.

Use case: I generate screenshots from our app with an XCTest target. I like to add some text with an custom font.

So i need a custom font in the test target, but not in the main app.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load a font from the test target just run this inside the test bundle:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:fontFileName ofType:@"ttf"];
NSData *inData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

CFErrorRef error;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)inData);
CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
    CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
    NSLog(@"Error loading font: %@", errorDescription);
    CFRelease(errorDescription);
}
CFRelease(font);
```